# HTTP SET-Cookie in response header is not set in broswer

Tags: http, cookies, express

I set the cookie in the response header at below

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By    Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Expose-Headers   Set-Cookie
Set-Cookie  name=tom; Path=/
Set-Cookie  _id=j%3A%2255dd7fcf5aef5fd13f6a2621%22; Max-Age=720; Domain=xx.xx.xx.xx; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 28 Aug 2015 07:13:12 GMT; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie  token=cd279529eb6868ba0cca2aed24690bf6; Max-Age=720; Domain=xx.xx.xx.xx; Path=/; Expires=Fri, 28 Aug 2015 07:13:12 GMT; HttpOnly
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But I cannot see the cookies are stored in my browser

Comment: How are you checking if they are stored in your browser?

Comment: run document.cookie in console

Comment: The purpose of `HttpOnly` cookies is that they cannot be accessed through Javascript on the client, which explains why you don't see them. Try using the developer tools of your browser instead.